# Exiting a do while loop at !=EOF using scanf in C makes 3 extra iterations

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, eof

I have some problems with this code

I'm trying to read a .txt through stdin, specifically the steps I follow to compile are:

```
g++ eda.c -o eda.exe
./eda.exe < eda.txt
```

And the content of the .txt file is:

```
3
[9.3,1.2,87.9]
[1.0,1.0]
[0.0,0.0,1.0]
print v3
incr v3 v1
```

The first 4 lines have no interest now, these lines have been already read with getline instruction. So the question starts from the fifth line, "incr ..."

With that line, I expect an output like: `print!` but I get:

`print!
print!
print!`

(and the same with `incr`)

The specific part of the code that reads `incr`and `print`starts with:
`char mystring [20];`

NOTE: 
Solved using fgets()!

This is the final code:

```
do {
        //sscanf (mystring,"%s",str);
        //int res = strncmp(str, "incr", 10);
        if(mystring[0] == 'p') casenumber = 1;
        else if(mystring[0] == 'i') casenumber = 2;
        else if(mystring[0] == 'd' && mystring[1] == 'o') casenumber = 3;
        else if(mystring[0] == 'd' && mystring[1] == 'i') casenumber = 4;
        else if(mystring[0] == 'd' && mystring[1] == 'e') casenumber = 5;

        switch(casenumber)
        {
        case 1 :
            printf("print!\n" );
            break;
        case 2 :
            printf("increase!\n");
            break;
        case 3 :
            printf("dot!\n");
            break;
        case 4 :
            printf("distance!\n");
            break;
        case 5 :
            printf("decr!\n");
            break;
       default :
            printf("casenumber value is: %d\n", casenumber);
            break;
        }
        casenumber = 0;
    } while (fgets (mystring , 21 , stdin) != NULL);
```

Comment: Reviewing code on SO is painful.

Comment: Your do-while should be a `while(scanf("%19s", mystring) == 1){...}` You're ignoring the result immediately after you get it, then treating  `mystring[]` like it actually worked. And honestly, you should be line-processing this via `fgets()`

Comment: Why do you post all that code unrelated to this problem? Please try to reduce it to a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think you are right in all, fgets() is a good option too but how can I do the loop with fgets()?

Comment: Read `fgets()` manual , it return NULL when fail to read

Comment: @Gerard The same way you are now, but slurp you individual parameters via text processing the line buffer. As written this is rather brittle. And "...my teacher only allows me to use that compiler + C code".. You teacher needs to get a reality check and understand C and C++ are different languages and contrary to widely held belief in academia, one is *not* an all-encompassing superset of the other.

Comment: @MartinR I do it because maybe is related to the fact that the code does not work well ... and I don't know the reason for which the output is repeated three times...

Comment: @Gerard: You should be able to reduce your program to a much smaller one (say, 20 lines or shorter) that exhibits the same symptom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to print the result of scanf?

scanf do not read a line, it reads a simple string, so your code will loop more times than you are expecting.

Other issues...

Clear your variable every run inside the loop.

```
casenumber = 0;
memset(mystring, 0, sizeof(mystring));
```

And test the result of scanf

```
if ( result == 1 )
    printf("sscanf error");
```